# How to get data for a given search query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a table for ManyToMany relationship. Where each Tutor need to input multiple days that he wants to tutor student. Like:

```
    Availability Tutor:
  
 user  available_day    time 
  
  t1    Sun              6,7,8
  t2    mon              3,4
  t1    mon              1,2
```

I would like to get all tutor where availablity is based on search day.

Model:

```
class TutorProfile(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    tutor_availablility = models.ManyToManyField(
        Day)
```

queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    subject_param = self.request.GET.get('subject')

    bookday = self.request.GET.get('book_day')
    grade = self.request.GET.get('grade')

    
   
    li = list(bookday.split(","))
    print("Book Info:", li)
    
    for i in range(len(li)):

        print(li[i])
        _day_name = datetime.strptime(li[i], "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%A")

        print("Day Name:", _day_name)

        day_num = Day.objects.get(day_name=_day_name)

        print("Day_Num",day_num)

        result = TutorProfile.objects.filter(
                tutor_availablility=day_num).all()

        return result
```

When I run this query it only loop over one time for one day but not for multiple days.

[image]

[image]

Now how may I run this query so that it will not stop after one loop.

After One loop it says: An exception occurred
An exception occurred

I tried to apply try catch block here. But getting no clue. Why stop loop after one cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one loop, you are returning the results. Instead, use the [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object to store the conditions and then filter the queryset outside of the for loop:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
query = Q()
for i in range(len(li)):
    _day_name = datetime.strptime(li[i], "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%A")
    day_num = Day.objects.get(day_name=_day_name)

    query2 = query | Q(
             tutor_availablility=day_num)

return TutorProfile.objects.filter(query)
```

### Update

Although the following code should not change the outcome, but try like this:

```
li = list(bookday.split(","))
query = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%A"), li)
return TutorProfile.objects.filter(tutor_availability__day_name__in = query)
```

Comment: Your Answered helped here. Now I am getting all data. Problem is that it also returns all those object those are not matched with any day.

Comment: `li = list(bookday.split(","))
        query = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%A"), li))
        return TutorProfile.objects.filter(tutor_availablility__day_name__in = query)`